# How do I set an Android ProgressBar's Size programmatically?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a custom view that extends `ViewGroup`. It includes a `ProgressBar` and a `WebView`. I'm displaying the `ProgressBar` while the `WebView` is loading.

This works, but the `ProgressBar` is too big. How do I make it smaller?

Below is my non-working code:

```
webView = new WebView(context);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file://" + path);
addView(webView);

progressBar = new ProgressBar(mContext, null,
                                         android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
progressBar.setLayoutParams(params);

addView(progressBar);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use LayoutParams to change width and height to whatever you want.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(teste.this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 10);

            progressBar.setLayoutParams(params );
            LinearLayout test = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            test.addView(progressBar);
            setContentView(test);
```

Also when you add a view, you can use this code:
`test.addView(progressBar,50,50);` where the first parameter is width and the second is height.

Answer (score 23):

You can also set the size of your progressbar from within the xml, just use `android:maxHeight`, `android:minHeight`, `android:minWidth` and `android:maxWidth` properties inside your `ProgressBar` tag.

for instance, this will set the height of the progressbar to `35dip` and width to `10dip`,

```
   <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"
    android:maxHeight="35dip"
    android:minHeight="35dip"

    android:minWidth="10dip"
    android:maxWidth="10dip"

    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 11):

In the **xml**, set the style, **for example,**

> **style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"**

```
<ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do via scaleX and scaleY property, here's how:

```
progressBar.scaleX=0.5f
progressBar.scaleY=0.5f
```

Here,

**scaleX:** To change the width, so 0.5 will reduce the width to the half of the actual width

**scaleY:** To change the height, so 0.5 will reduce the height to the half of actual height

Answer (score 3):

**The easies way is by scale:**

```
public class CustomProgressBarRenderer :ProgressBarRenderer
{
  protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
  {
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    Control.ProgressDrawable.SetColorFilter(Color.FromRgb(182, 231, 233).ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
    Control.ProgressTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.FromRgb(182, 231, 233).ToAndroid());
    Control.ScaleY = 10; // This changes the height

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's give it a try...

I have fix the `size` of progressBar with add some `padding`.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="45dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/category_img"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: adjusting padding gives us progressbar in required sizes :)

Answer (score -1):

Single line solution, try this

```
progressBar.setPadding(0,24,0,24);//left,top,right,bottom
```