# Can I set dimensions ( width ) of progress dialog and how?

Tags: java, android

I need to show `ProgressDialog` with message and I am doing this like

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this,
  "Connecting...", "Please wait",
  true, false
);
```

Can I set dimensions ( width ) of progress dialog and how ? It works but it looks small and ugly.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496976/how-do-i-set-an-android-progressbars-size-programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set an Android ProgressBar's Size programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496976/how-do-i-set-an-android-progressbars-size-programmatically)

Comment: @LukasKnuth & Manu ProgressBar != ProgressDialog (though the same *answer* may well apply)

Answer (score 0):

## What I want:

What I want is a clean loading indicator on the center of the screen, with user interaction disabled, programmatically.

## The problem

The problem is that by default, the dialog box is set to be fill_parent for width. If I use a custom indicator view (`AVLoadingIndicatorView`in this example), it stays on the left side and is very ugly.

## The solution

You need to add in a custom style for the `ProgressDialog`, asking it to wrap content for width. It will be centered by default.

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!--Other custom stuff if needed-->
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Then here is the sample code using `AVLoadingIndicatorView`. You can substitute it with whatever custom view you want.

```
AVLoadingIndicatorView avLoadingIndicatorView=new AVLoadingIndicatorView(getActivity(), null, 50, 50);
avLoadingIndicatorView.setIndicator("BallPulseSyncIndicator");
avLoadingIndicatorView.setIndicatorColor(R.color.colorPrimary);

final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogStyle);
mDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
mDialog.show();
mDialog.setContentView(avLoadingIndicatorView);
```

And the final result looks like this: (My emulator is slow as always)

[image]

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47099743) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)