# Android: Progress dialog size

Tags: android, dialog, size, width, progress

I have created an app with progress dialog for open a new activity. The default is the width of the text. As I can do to always occupy the width of the screen. thanks

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.Theme_MyDialog);
pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pDialog.setMessage("DIALOG");
pDialog.setCancelable(true);
pDialog.setMax(100);

pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ...
    }
});

pDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar)pDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
        v.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Modulo.coloresListview
                (MainActivity.this, 
                perfilObj.getColor())[1],
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    }
});

pDialog.setProgress(0);
pDialog.show();
```

EDIT

[MY CURRENT PROGRESS](http://thorbek.net/online/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/loading.jpg)

[MY WHISED PROGRESS](http://rusproject.narod.ru/android/wheelprogress.png)

**STYLE**

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparente</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: show me one screen shot or clear your question.

Comment: Please see the answer at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496976/how-do-i-set-an-android-progressbars-size-programmatically

Comment: I have edite my code with current and whised progress. I want this style

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the link [How do I set an Android ProgressBar's Size programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496976/how-do-i-set-an-android-progressbars-size-programmatically) as @joao2fast4u suggested.
and use below code for width of screen that will be set in layout params.

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();

```
    try { 
        display.getRealSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y; 
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        screenHeight = display.getHeight();
    }
```

Comment: I have edite my code with current and whised progress. I want this style